# How to resolve npm run dev missing script issues?

Tags: node.js, webpack, git-bash

I am currently in the folder 'C:\Users\vignesh\Documents\Personal Projects\Full-Stack-Web-Developement' on gitbash

**npm run dev**

executing the above command on gitbash gives me the following error.
I am assuming this is due to the NODE_PATH variables not being set properly.
Please let me know if anyone has a solution to the below problem

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v4.4.6
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5

npm ERR! missing script: dev
```

Comment: It means it can't find a script called dev - should it be  in your package.json?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The issue is now resolved! I included dev in package.json.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
npm run <command>
```

will run bash script from package.json from 'scripts' value of '' attribute. For example:

*package.json*

```
{
   "name": "app",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "license": "MIT",
   "scripts": {
      "server": "webpack-dashboard -- webpack-dev-server --inline --port 8080",
      "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
   },
  "dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
   "@angular/core": "~2.2.0"
   },
  "devDependencies": {
   "@types/core-js": "^0.9.0"
   }
}
```

In this case you can run scripts:

```
npm run server
npm run webdriver-update
```

In your case you probably wont have *dev* script.

Remember that few scripts name are reserved (for example *npm test* will try to run, *npm run pretest, npm run test, npm run posttest*). More info on https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: Thanks a lot! The issue is now resolved! I included dev in package.json.

Comment: Great explanantion!

Answer (score 18):

Simply check the package.json file and see what the name of the key is for dev. In my case it was start instead of dev, so I ran `npm run start` and that did it.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

**Adding**

```
  "scripts": {
       "dev": "nodemon server.js",  
  },
```

to your **package.json** resolves the problem.
Make sure nodemon is installed/added as a dependency.

Answer (score 5):

After you install:

```
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Go in the package.json and add `"dev": "nodemon ./bin/www"`
[image]

Answer (score 3):

1) In the npm package.json script, define a script like this:

```
"start:dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack/webpack.config.dev.js,
```

Note: if it is not the last statement ends with a comma.

2) run the below statement in terminal

```
npm run start:dev
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the package.json file and see whether it is dev. I face the exact problem and in my case, it started. so I used the command `npm run start` and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved by simply checking to see if I was inside the project folder with this command:

> **cd project_name**

(replace the words project_name with the folder name of where your project is found or the name of your project.

Then running the **npm run dev** again

Answer (score 1):

Your `package.json` is missing a `dev` key in the scripts section. Or you are running the `npm` command from a wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

"scripts": {

"dev": "nodemon server.js",

},

Add this code to your package.json file and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, check that you are inside the main project. Then try the solutions in this page
2. NOTE : After running **ex- npx create-next-app** command you will be creating a directory for the project. Then you have to move inside the created project by **cd project_name**