# Npm not running in terminal vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, vite

What I typed:

```
npm run dev
```

**Error**:

```bash
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!  C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-12T04_58_51_898Z-debug.log
```

**Json:**

```json
{
  "name": "port",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^2.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.134.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto you project directory by `cd your-project-name`.
run `npm run dev` command and try again (In your **npm** command "N" is capital).
and if not work please check below link (please refer green tick answer) :

[How to resolve npm run dev missing script issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129815/how-to-resolve-npm-run-dev-missing-script-issues/49057746)