# I keep typing "npm run dev" and it keeps saying missing script: "dev"

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, powershell

I'm a total Newbie to doing code and I'm currently watching a Three.js Beginner's Tutorial (I'm using VisualStudio)

I've enabled scripts already on powershell

And I'm at the part where he's typing, `npm run dev` in the terminal and for his part it went smooth but mine it keeps saying missing script: `dev`

```
 npm ERR! Missing script: "Dev"
 
npm ERR!  
 npm ERR! To see a list of
 scripts, run: 

npm ERR!   npm run
 
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Here's what my package.json looks like

```
 "name": "myproject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^3.1.0"
```

How do I fix this problem? Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve npm run dev missing script issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129815/how-to-resolve-npm-run-dev-missing-script-issues)

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like, can you post it? Using `npm run <command>` will only run commands that exist in the `scripts` section of the package.json

Comment: It looks like this, 

  "name": "myproject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^3.1.0"

Comment: Is your terminal in the project's directory?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install  `npm i install` maybe and can you try again to run your project. beside that, if you have to change your script run?
if ever, change it to the way it was